# cleveref breaks \appendix with optional argument defined in IEEEtran

Tags: sectioning, appendices, ieeetran, cleveref

I think the title says it all. Including `cleveref` in this MWE changes how the output looks:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
% \usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
    \appendix[Appendix headline]
\end{document}
```

Is there an option to prevent that? I have looked at the `cleveref` manual, but haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is fixed in the pre-release versions (0.21) available from my web site, and quite possibly also in the previous pre-release (0.20): http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex.html

At least, the MWE produces identical output with and without cleveref.

Comment: Having checked out v0.21, I believe you are right :) Also, I am glad to see the enum-sort bug has been fixed. Finally, I have replaced v0.19 by v0.21 in my 30-page document without seeing any difference, so it only got better. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The fastest and easiest way is for sure to save the meaning of `\appendix` before loading `cleveref` and restore it to that after loading the package:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\let\ieeeappendix\appendix
\usepackage{cleveref}
\let\appendix\ieeeappendix

\begin{document}
\appendix[Appendix headline]
\end{document}
```

Note however, that this might restrict the functionality of `cleveref`.

Comment: "Note however, that this might restrict the functionality of `cleveref`." - Yes, a reference to a `section` in the appendix becomes `section A` rather than `appendix A`. Fortunately, without `\section` commands, `\cref` does not work properly anyway, so much is not lost ;)

Answer (score 3):

Give `IEEEtran` a chance to maintain its definition of `\appendix` by using `\AtBeginDocument{...}` and a more robust version of `\appendix`.

Since `IEEEtran` uses `\refstepcounter{section}` in the `\appendix` code, `\label` will store this information, so `cleveref` will always report `Section` instead of `Appendix`. Use `\label[appendix]{foo}` instead then.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\ieeetran@appendix\appendix
\AtBeginDocument{%
\RenewDocumentCommand{\appendix}{o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \ieeetran@appendix[#1]%
  }{%
    \ieeetran@appendix%
  }%
}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
See \Cref{appone}

\appendix \label[appendix]{appone}

\appendix[Appendix headline] \label{apptwo}
\end{document}
```

[image]